# internal-sftp log for chrooted group

Tags: server, ssh, log, chroot, sftp

My `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` file have follow config

```
Subsystem sftp internal-sftp -f AUTH -l INFO
Match group tmrhackers
ChrootDirectory %h
ForceCommand internal-sftp
AllowTcpForwarding no
```

and the sftp work fine with chroot.
[The official troubleshooting](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Logging_and_Troubleshooting) suggest

> Logging the built-in sftp-subsystem inside a chroot jail, defined by ChrootDirectory, needs a ./dev/log node to exist inside the jail.

However here is a group with many user,do I need to add `./dev/log` in every users home path or do I have some way to work around?

Answer (score 2):

> However here is a group with many user,do I need to add ./dev/log in every users home path or do I have some way to work around?

Yes. There is currently no other way around, until [other way will be accepted upstream in OpenSSH 7.6](https://bugzilla.mindrot.org/show_bug.cgi?id=2681) or you will use something else (Fedora, RHEL) that already has this functionality.

Comment: after `mkdir /dev/log` and `systemctl restart sshd` I still can't see `INFO` level log in `/vat/log/auth.log`.If there something else need to be done?

Comment: You need to add this socket (full path) to the `syslog` to gather the information from it). Also the `log` is not a directory!

Comment: I tried `sudo syslogd -a /home/user/dev/log` but still didn't find the `INFO` level log in `syslog` or `auth.log`.